# TypeError at /website/login/:login() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django

I am creating a website using Django and i am a beginner in it.

views.py:

```
def login(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      user=form.get_user()
      login(request,user)
      if 'next' in request.POST:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(request.POST.get('next')))
      else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('website:books'))
    else:
      return render(request,'website/login.html')
  else:
    form=AuthenticationForm()
  return render(request,'website/login.html',{'form':form})
```

The error i am getting is:

```
File "D:\playground\blog\website\views.py", line 16, in login
login(request,user)
TypeError: login() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
[10/Mar/2020 14:34:57] "POST /website/login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 74342
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your custom function is called "login" and then you are trying to call the django function from `django.contrib.auth` which is also called `login`.

Look on that line and you call `login(request,user)`

So the fix is one of these

1. Rename your view to something other than login
2. In the import use ["as"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/) to alias the existing function to something else.  E.G. `from django.contrib.auth import login as django_login` then change `login(request,user)` for `django_login(request,user)`

Comment: Yeah . I got that . Thanks